# Why ssize_t in Visual Studio 2010 is defined as unsigned?

Tags: c, windows, types

I have a portable program which uses ssize_t under the assumption it is a signed integer. Conceptually it does something like:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    size_t size_10 = 10;
    size_t size_20 = 20;
    ssize_t len_diff;
    len_diff = (ssize_t)size_10 - (ssize_t)size_20;
    if (len_diff < 0)
        printf("negative\n");
    else if (len_diff > 0)
        printf("positive\n");
    else
        printf("zero\n");
}
```

One would expect the program to print 'negative' but instead it prints 'positive'. The reason is easy to see from how ssize_t is defined (in sourceannotations.h):

```
#ifndef _SSIZE_T_DEFINED
#ifdef  _WIN64
typedef unsigned __int64    ssize_t;
#else
typedef _W64 unsigned int   ssize_t;
#endif
#define _SSIZE_T_DEFINED
#endif
```

And so, subtracting two unsigned values results in an unsigned value and hence the result.

In older versions of the Windows SDK (e.g. V7.0A) the ssize_t was correctly defined as:

```
//
// SIZE_T used for counts or ranges which need to span the range of
// of a pointer.  SSIZE_T is the signed variation.
//

typedef ULONG_PTR SIZE_T, *PSIZE_T;
typedef LONG_PTR SSIZE_T, *PSSIZE_T;
```

Can anyone explain this change? Are we supposed to stop using ssize_t  on Windows?

*Update:*
Based on all the answers, it appears to be a bug in Visual Studio 2010 which includes ssize_t but defined incorrectly. This is a sneaky and nasty bug.

*Last Update:*
This bug has been fixed in VS2012 and VS2016. Also from the comment discussion it appears that this way of calculating len_diff is problematic when the values compared are of different signs when casted to SSIZE_T

Comment: It is a bug in V7.0A.  According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx signed size_t is LONG_PTR.

Comment: @EdS.: Thus the "or". :-)

Comment: @R..: ...fair enough.  It's really pretty crazy that they defined the *signed* version of `size_t` as unsigned.

Comment: @EdS.: It looks to me like the all-caps, MS-style `SSIZE_T` is correct and it's just the POSIX-style `ssize_t` that's broken, so I suspect this is yet another subtle attempt to break portable cross-platform code and force Windows-specific `#ifdef`s...

Comment: @R.. And what would they gain by adding something like that? It's an obvious bug shedding a bad light at their own product they try to sell. Who in their right mind would do that? It's not like that would get more people into using MSVC, it's more likely the opposite. Just look at the comments here so far.

Comment: @R.. The mentioned `ssize_t` buggy definition isn't present in VC2012

Comment: Judging by the comments here... looks like they got what they wanted. Exposure and publicity, search engine association, etc... Have you considered that maybe the world isn't 100% fluffy roses and that companies that are ahead *did stuff* to get ahead?

Comment: *Are we supposed to stop using ssize_t on Windows?* `s/ssize_t on//`

Comment: But but but, `ifndef`and `typedef`are 2 separate universes: precompiler ans compiler... It should not interract, should it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ssize_t` is **not** standard C, it is a typedef from Posix.  That you found it in a code analysis header for VS2010 probably has something to do with the origin, most code analysis tooling started on Unix.  It is removed again in VS2012 and up.

That it is present in the BaseTsd.h SDK file *in all caps* certainly is not a mistake, Windows supported a Posix subsystem.  These typedefs insulate the operating system from compiler implementation details, the basic reason that Windows managed to survive architecture changes, moving from 16 to 32 to 64-bit.

So the *real* problem is that you are trying to compile a Posix program on Windows but without using Posix headers.  Trivial to solve, just add your own typedef before the #includes.

Comment: Thanks Hans, but the typedef appears in sourceannotations.h which annotates all APIs with in/out/... macros so it is included by default with just stdint.h and stdio.h -- the "posix" code in question is LMDB (http://symas.com/mdb/) and it is one of huge number of 'portable' libraries. It still makes no sense why, if they bother to defined ssize_t, they explicitly define it in the wrong way (as is evident by the all-caps version which is defined correcrtly).

Answer (score 29):

Would this be a good solution?

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#include <BaseTsd.h>
typedef SSIZE_T ssize_t;
#endif
```

Comment: This is another good solution. Usually, it is paired with other #defines that go inside `#if __INTELLISENSE__`. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Although it's definitely not conforming the POSIX standard to have `ssize_t` being an unsigned integer, the OP's code risks to also break on systems conforming the POSIX standard.

As [POSIX defines `ssize_t` to (at least) just cover the `-1` and nothing else negativ](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html):

> **ssize_t**
>
> Used for a count of bytes or an error indication.
>
> [...]
>
> The type **ssize_t** shall be capable of storing values at least in the range [-1, {SSIZE_MAX}].

Comment: Interesting, so it's supposed to be `size_t` but with a value reserved for error handling?

Comment: My guess is that if the value is too large for the number of bits, -1 is used as an overflow holder and errstr

Comment: `size_t` and `ssize_t` are just broken standardization, very hard to mix them 100% portably, as they have different range of possible positive values. There should be just one of them to facilitate writing robust code.

Comment: @Mario Yes, the typical use case of `ssize_t` is for the return value of `read(2)`.

Comment: @alk Yes, I want to see the chip designer who would, jjust for the kick of it, develop a CPU with a basic scalar type to match this SSIZE_T definition covering the range [-1, {SSIZE_MAX}].

However, you raised a valid point that the code is problematic in case the values cross the half value of the unsigned quantity. The comparison breaks across that half point for example with the casted values 1, 10, -10, -1 -- here we'll get (1,10)=>Negative, (10,-10)=>Positive which would be a bug (in the original code)